# Continue a task in While Loop

Tags: c#, .net

Im trying to move data from SQL to MongoDB. Question is related to C# Async Await. What I do is collect 2000 documents first and then insert into MongoDB. I am awaiting my insert call. What I want to do here is instead of waiting I want to continue collecting next 2000 documents but only call the SaveToCollection method only if last call is returned.

```
int counter = 0, totalCounter = 0;
List<BsonDocument> documentList = new List<BsonDocument>();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Dictionary<string, object> obj = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    for (int lp = 0; lp < rdr.FieldCount; lp++)
    {
        if (rdr.GetValue(lp) != DBNull.Value)
            obj.Add(rdr.GetName(lp).ToLower(), rdr.GetValue(lp));
        else
            obj.Add(rdr.GetName(lp).ToLower(), "");
    }
    documentList.Add(new BsonDocument(obj));
    counter++;
    if (counter == 2000)
    {
        /* I dont want to wait here. Continue to get 2000 more documents but wait if previous call is not completed yet.*/
        if (SaveToCollection(documentList, MongoCollectionName).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
        {
            totalCounter = totalCounter + counter;
        }
        documentList.Clear();
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: A very simplistic solution would be:

    Task task = null;
    while (rdr.Read())
    ...
    if (counter == 200)
    {
       task?.Wait();
       if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RunToCompletion)
       {
          totalCounter = totalCounter + 200;
       }
       task = SaveToCollection(documentList, MongoCollectionName);
       documentList = new List<BsonDocument>();
       counter = 0;
    }

Comment: @Marco This is what im looking for. Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: @Marco works like a charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use `Task.Run()`; and save the returned task object. You can then await it on the next loop around before continuing

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` is extremely discouraged unless you are forced to use .NET 4.0. Use `Task.Run` in .NET 4.5 onwards

Comment: Thank you for that, I should have known :) I'll edit my answer